# I need to see new commits on remote git repo

Tags: git

My problem is how to see new commits on remote git repo after I made a shallow clone of the repo.This is needed for consecutive downloading this new specific commits without huge history tail

Comment: Why not just do an occasional pull after `git clone --depth n`? You'll only then get the diffs from your initial shallow clone

Comment: I tried this idea and git started to download above 4 million objects

Comment: When I do pull ,got starts to download all previously counted objects(above 4 mln)

Comment: So what do you want - see new commits on a specific branch only, without downloading the entire git repo?

Comment: Yes this is first step.And after to download this precise number of commits only

Answer (score 0):

You could do a git fetch --depth=depthValue and then use git log.

Comment: I also like this method but when choosing depth too little it later causes difficulties with merging due to skipping a couple of commits between say remote/master and local master.That is why I asked how to know in advance the number of new commits on remote repo since shallow clone to be able to concisely download them only

Answer (score 0):

You could do

`git fetch`

to get the remote refs and then

`git log HEAD..remote/branch`

to see the newer commits on the remote.

Comment: Or `git remote update`. But the problem here is that running `git fetch` will download every remote object, which is precisely what you _don't_ want to do in a shallow clone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--single-branch` option to limit cloning to a single branch only. This will skip downloading all the other branches, and hence your local git clone will be much smaller in size.

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://domain.com/repo.git
```

Later, you can use these commands to list all new commits that are present on remote repo, but not on your local:

```
git fetch
git log HEAD..remote/mybranch
```

And, of course, you can update your local repo as usually by pulling all the commits from remote:

```
git pull
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue recently and for me It appears that the local repository's master branch lacks a tracking branch. so all I did was

```
git branch -u origin/master
```

After this when the next issue that will be complaining about history within the origin/master - just got for the force option as I have noticed nothing hectic tends to happen.

I hope it helps someone :)
I stay corrected

Comment: You have not understood the question.